# How to change boolean value on click in angular 2 component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**How do I connect the button to change the values of the [codeOnly] values in the directives below it?**

I'm using Angular 2.4.10 in typescript.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">
     Click me to change all of the [codeOnly] values below to true
</button>

<app-header [codeOnly]='false'></app-header>

<app-power-bi-wrapper [codeOnly]='false'></app-power-bi-wrapper>

<app-power-bi-wrapper-mobile [codeOnly]='false'></app-power-bi-wrapper-mobile>

<app-page-title [codeOnly]='false'></app-page-title>

<app-page-title-nav [codeOnly]='false'></app-page-title-nav>
```

Comment: You'd have to use the same variable to pass in to both of them.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In the component that contains your HTML add

```
isFoo:boolean = false;
```

then change the HTML to

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="isFoo = true" >
     Click me to change all of the [codeOnly] values below to true
</button>

<app-header [codeOnly]='isFoo'></app-header>

<app-power-bi-wrapper [codeOnly]='isFoo'></app-power-bi-wrapper>

<app-power-bi-wrapper-mobile [codeOnly]='isFoo'></app-power-bi-wrapper-mobile>

<app-page-title [codeOnly]='isFoo'></app-page-title>

<app-page-title-nav [codeOnly]='isFoo'></app-page-title-nav>
```

or to toggle

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="isFoo = !isFoo" >
     Click me to change all of the [codeOnly] values below to true
</button>
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. `isFoo = !isFoo` just toggles isFoo between true and false on each click event.